# Why I can access absoluteUrl from RunWrapper instance

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy

I am working on a Jenkins Pipeline, in its script, I saw the code like below:

```
    def jobResult = build job: "SomeJobName" ...

    println jobResult.absoluteUrl
```

I looked up some reference for the build step's return type, then I know it is actually [RunWrapper class](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-support-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.java#L183) in the underneath Java implementation for Jenkins, from its documentation, it only has getter for that name(no public field named "absoluteUrl") as below:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Whitelisted
    public @NonNull String getAbsoluteUrl() throws AbortException {
        return build().getAbsoluteUrl();
    }
```

I wonder why that jobResult.absoluteUrl can work in the script ? I guess it is a feature of Groovy not Java ? I also found this reference of Groovy below from [here](https://groovy-lang.org/objectorientation.html#properties):

> Properties are accessed by name and will call the getter or setter transparently

as an additional curiosity, can someone gives me some brief introduction to How Groovy utilizing Java under the hood ? Thank you.

Comment: You can start [Here](https://groovy-lang.org/objectorientation.html#properties)